# Step in building up spectral sequences

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

I'm currently reading Timothy Chow's [article](http://www.ams.org/notices/200601/fea-chow.pdf) defining spectral sequences, and I'm stuck on one step. Here is a summary:

We have a finite-dimensional chain complex $... \overset{\partial}{\longrightarrow} C_{d+1} \overset{\partial}{\longrightarrow} C_d \overset{\partial}{\longrightarrow} ...$ which has a two-layered filtration, *ie*, for any $d$, we have:

$0 = C_{d, 0} \subset C_{d,1} \subset C_{d,2} = C_d$. A fortiori, there also is such a filtration for the set of boundaries $B_d$, and the set of cycles $Z_d \subset C_d$.

---

We go on to define an associated complex by $E_{d,p}^0 := C_{d,p}/C_{d, p-1}$ with induced map $\partial^0$. And its homology $E_{d,p}^{1} := H_d(E_{d,p}^0) = \dfrac{\ker\{\partial^0 : E_{d,2}^0 \longrightarrow E_{d-1,2}^0\}}{\text{im}\{\partial^0 : E_{d+1,2}^0 \longrightarrow E_{d,2}^0\}}$.

So far, so good. Now, the paper (page 3) tries to analyse the difference between that homology, and that of the original complex (whose $d$-th homology group would simply be $Z_d/B_d$).

Now here is the part that I struggle to understand (I attached a big screenshot for context but really the part I struggle with is the first line):

[image]

I don't see why the space of boundaries of $E_{d,2}^1$ would be $B_{d,2} + C_{d,1}$. Here was my train of thought:

The said space of boundaries is $\text{im}\{\partial^0 : E_{d+1,2}^0 \longrightarrow E_{d,2}^0\} = \text{im}\{\partial^0 : C_{d+1,2}/C_{d+1,1} \longrightarrow C_{d,2}/C_{d,1}\}$. Now, $\partial^0$ is constant on $C_{d+1,1}$, so the latter image is the same as $\text{im}\{\partial^0 : C_{d+1,2} \longrightarrow C_{d,2}/C_{d,1}\}$.

And since $\partial(C_{d+1,2}) = B_{d,2} \subset C_{d,2}$, then shouldn't we have:

$\text{im}\{\partial^0 : C_{d+1,2} \longrightarrow C_{d,2}/C_{d,1}\} = \dfrac{B_{d,2}}{B_{d,2}\cap C_{d,1}} = \dfrac{B_{d,2}}{B_{d,1}}$

Surely that is wrong, but I don't understand how to get to the result mentioned in the paper.

Moreover, the space of boundaries should be a subspace of $E_{d,2}^0 = C_{d,2}/C_{d,1}$. I don't see how we can view $B_{d,2} + C_{d,1}$ as a subspace of the latter.

Thanks for reading, I hope this was clear! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what is meant is not that $B_{d,2}+C_{d,1}$ is a subspace of $E^0_{d,2}$. Let me try to rephrase the image you linked. We are looking at the following diagram (sorry, I don't know how to draw inclusion arrows with AMScd).

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
C_{d+1,2} @>>> C_{d,2} @>f>> C_{d-1,2}\\
@AAA @AAA @AAA\\
C_{d+1,1} @>>> C_{d,1} @>>> C_{d-1,1}
\end{CD}$$

What the author says is that $E^1_{d,2}$ is isomorphic to $\frac{f^{-1}(C_{d-1,1})}{B_{d,2}+C_{d,1}}$. To see that, complete the diagram as follows.

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @. 0 @. 0\\
@AAA @AAA @AAA\\
E^0_{d+1,2} @>v>> E^0_{d,2} @>u>> E^0_{d-1,2}\\
@AAA @AAgA @AAA\\
C_{d+1,2} @>>> C_{d,2} @>f>> C_{d-1,2}\\
@AAA @AAA @AAA\\
C_{d+1,1} @>>> C_{d,1} @>>> C_{d-1,1}
\end{CD}$$

Then
$$\begin{align*}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}\ker(u)/\im(v) &= g^{-1}(\ker(u))/g^{-1}(\im(v))\\
&= f^{-1}(C_{d-1,1})/(B_{d,2}+C_{d,1})\text{.}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :D That was very clear. I understand better where all of those come from. My only question is, how do you get the equality $\ker(u)/\text{im}(v) = g^{-1}(ker(u))/g^{-1}(im(v))$? $g$ is a quotient map, isn't it? So why should that equality hold

Comment: @Azur You're welcome. :) Given any quotient map $g : A↠B$, if $U⊆V⊆B$ are subspaces, then $V/U$ is isomorphic to $g^{-1}(V)/g^{-1}(U)$. Indeed, let $V' = g^{-1}(V)$, $U' = g^{-1}(U)$ and $K = \ker(g)$. We have $K ⊆ U' ⊆ V'$. Since $g$ is surjective, $V ≅ V'/K$ and similarly for $U$. So $V/U ≅ (V'/K)/(U'/K) ≅ V'/U'$. (Notice also that the equalities in my answer are rather isomorphisms.)

Comment: Thank you! That's very clear. Have a nice day :D